# Check STL bounds in Debug and Release with MinGW

Tags: c++, stl, indexoutofboundsexception, bounds-checker

I'm working on a project (settlers 2.5 return to the roots namely) which suffers some problems. I hope to be able to solve some of them by using only stl containers and bounds checking.

So is it somehow possible to use bounds-checking in STL containers also in release mode? So we could use a (less performing) version, that does them and crashes/throws on error?

The build server uses MinGW to crosscompile from linux to windows and apple.

Edit: []-operator is used exclusively. Changing to .at() would require a large search-and-replace action which got to be reversed at some point. Best would be, if there is a define or something that switches []-behaviour to .at()

Comment: Is this useful? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**

You can rely on exceptions to verify bound checking using STL container. This is enable in both debug and release mode.

For instance [std::vector::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) throws an out of range exception if beyond the bounds.

**Second approach**

If you use operator[] and you do not want to change your code, you can enable `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` flag for bound checking.

Comment: Yes but this requires rewriting almost the whole code. I thought about a flag or something like that.

Comment: So basically can you precise what are you using ? operator[] for instance ? If you have an example code it would be nice. I edited my answer for this case.

Comment: Does _GLIBCXX_DEBUG work in MinGW? I read about some issues of containers returning wrong values when this is set...

Comment: I am unaware of any such issues with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, noone has reported them to our bug database. There is a caveat that you must recompile everything with `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` because it changes the ABI of the containers.

Comment: It should since this is a port of gcc. I am not aware about the issues. If you have some links. The best way would be to try with some examples :)